# how to create trigger for dates already passed?

Tags: sqlite

i dont know how can i fix this problem i have this error
L'exécution s'est terminée avec des erreurs.
Résultat : near "SELECT": syntax error
I guess my comparison does not work here do you know what is the correct syntax to do that?

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS DatesRepresentations
BEFORE INSERT ON Representations_base
WHEN(NEW.dateRep < SELECT strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',datetime('now','localtime')))
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, ' Cannot insert a date already passed!');
 END;
```

Comment: Try to remove the `SELECT` in `WHEN`.

Comment: I did that I have no error but the trigger does not work .

Comment: Representations_base ( dateRep,noSpec)
when i insert ('10/12/2019 20:00', 2) no error is raised

Comment: That date format will not work. "10/12/2019 20:00" is _greater than_ "05/12/2021 20:00" because they are compared as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Dates that are not in the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` are not comparable.

First, store your dates in that format.

Then change your code to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS DatesRepresentations
BEFORE INSERT ON Representations_base
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN NEW.dateRep < datetime('now', 'localtime')
       THEN RAISE(ABORT, 'Cannot insert a date already passed!')
    END;  
END;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6ac73ad4eab1ee678c39324e9196f8ad).

Comment: I have no right to modify the database. isn't there a way to fix that without modification of the database?

Comment: @FaroqAl-Nadhari if you don't change the format of the dates you will have to use string functions to rearrange the date parts in all your queries so that you can compare the dates. This will lead to bad code and bad performance. Think about it.